# Need some help optimizing this mySQL query

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this query that runs to obtain 5 recent posts/topics from phpbb3. The forum has over 180,000 records. This current query takes 20 seconds on average to complete.. Any ideas how I might optimize it to make it faster?

```
SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_last_post_id, t.forum_id, p.post_id, p.poster_id, p.post_time, u.user_id, u.username
FROM phpbb_topics t, phpbb_forums f, phpbb_posts p, phpbb_users u
WHERE t.topic_id = p.topic_id AND
f.forum_id = t.forum_id AND
t.forum_id != 4 AND
t.topic_status <> 2 AND
p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id AND
p.poster_id = u.user_id
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: use joins to optimize

Comment: What TilT said, you should be using `JOIN`s instead of putting all of the join conditions in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: also, you can use EXPLAIN to see where adding indexes might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I believe the `t.topic_id = p.topic_id` clause is redundant because it is already implied by `p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id`. So try this simplified version:

```
SELECT
    t.topic_id,
    t.topic_title,
    t.topic_last_post_id,
    t.forum_id,
    p.post_id,
    p.poster_id,
    p.post_time,
    u.user_id,
    u.username
FROM phpbb_forums f
JOIN phpbb_topics t ON f.forum_id = t.forum_id
JOIN phpbb_posts p ON t.topic_id = p.topic_id
JOIN phpbb_users u ON p.poster_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    t.forum_id != 4 AND
    t.topic_status != 2
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Secondly, (and this will likely be the cause of the slowness) make sure you have an index on the following columns: `f.forum_id`, `t.forum_id`, `t.topic_id`, `p.topic_id`, `p.poster_id`, `u.user_id` and `t.topic_status`.

(<> and != are equivalent)

Comment: out of curiosity where it's said that comma separated joins are slower ?

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd, oh, it's not slower. The two styles will actually be executed in exactly the same way. I just find it easier to work with when the joins are explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to add some indexes to your tables.

Kindly read [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm) in which you can learn about the `EXPLAIN` command. This will enable you to see where the bottle necks of your query are and then you will see which indexes you need to create.

For example if you make a `JOIN` between two tables, you have to make sure that both fields have an index. Otherwise MySQL will have to do some extra work to manage crossing the tables. Also, I suggest you (if you haven't already) creating an index for the field you use to order the rows (`ORDER BY p.post_id`).. this will also help in the performance of the query, otherwise MySQL will have to create temporary tables to order the results and this is time consuming as well.

Hope this helps you